# Asp.Net Treeview ImageSet Trouble

Tags: asp.net, treeview

http://www.imageupload.co.uk/5JwE

Treeview imageset is broken.
Anyone knows how to solve this? I don't want to create entire project from zero. Help me please :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. How is the treeview broken? What does that mean? Please provide the relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: After I installed angular js from nuget manager, treeview was like in the picture above. I reloaded all css files and problem solved. Thank you for your fast reply!